# list to dataframe in python, number of non-matching columns

Tags: python, pandas

This is a example data set.

1.original data

```
a:10
b:20
c:30

a:40
c:60
```

2. split ':', and make this (I did it)

```
a, 10, b, 20, c, 30
a, 40, c, 60
```

3. how to the list to dataframe? (my question)
   in this form

```
a  b  c
========
10 20 30
40 na 60
```

I think

```
range (i in 1:len(list)) 
list[0][2n] is colum names
list[0][2n+1] is value
```

and
list[0], list[1] merge

but I can not write good code
please give me hint

Comment: Are there line endings in the data? How do you read the data? Is it a  text file?

Comment: original data ```'a:10 b:20 c:30''a:40 c:60'``` sorry. I can't understand line endigs. It is from html by web crawling.

Comment: is there an empty space between every pair or are these really concatenated like this ```c:30''a:40```

Comment: ```list[0] is 'a:10 b:20 c:30', list[1] is 'a:40 c:60'``` ' is python symbols displayed in Python results. I accumulated data from web pages in order. As I know, there is no empty space.

Comment: I see! there is ```\r``` line endigs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can repeat `split`, `explode` then pivot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col":['a:10 b:20 c:30','a:40 c:60']})

print (df["col"].str.split()
                .explode()
                .str.split(":", expand=True)
                .set_index(0, append=True)[1]
                .unstack())

0   a    b   c
0  10   20  30
1  40  NaN  60
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not override the default list as a variable. If you want to use a generic variable name for a list convention is to use lst. You can create the necessary data with list comprehensions and pivot.

```
lst[0] = 'a:10 b:20 c:30'
lst[1]='a:40 c:60' 

lst = [map(lambda x: x.split(':'),text.split())  for text in lst]

data = [(i, column, value) for i, pair in enumerate(lst) for (column, value) in pair]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['index', 'columns', 'values']).pivot(values='values', columns='columns', index='index')
```